# What are some possible reasons that UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization might not prompt?

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

What are some possible reasons that `UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization` might not prompt?

I have some users that are not receiving the prompt for permission at all. I've even tried to change the app bundle Id in TestFlight to see if they would get the prompt but to no avail.

I've tried resetting permission via `https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG42` as well.

Notification permission settings does not get listed within the app settings on iOS which leads me to believe it isn't necessarily rejected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I don't think this is a code issue as the call is fairly straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

- Asking for `provisional` permissions causes the permission prompt for notifications not to show on iOS < 12.
- If the user has rejected the permission for your app before, then the dialog won't show either.

Comment: Sorry - turns out we just failed to detect that the app is native since we are doing WK WebView. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Even though the problem was caused by something silly; I think it would still be worthwhile to share the problem resolution.

We have a WK WebView iOS app. On our Angular side, we try to detect whether or not the environment is currently iOS native app before trying to prompt the user for permission. We do this detection by setting a flag in local storage (I don't really have all the details as it is not my code - I'm just the reviewer). Between the loading of the native app, the WebView and angular code, we couldn't reliably ensure that things are handled synchronously.

The detection failed - so we never prompt the user.

Thanks again for the help.